# Dynamics CRM 2016 - Creating History Log

Tags: logging, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have new small Dynamics CRM 2016 system without server side infrastructure and I would like to keep it that way.

I'm trying to create history log for some entity that should include previous and new value.

The history log should be created on any CRUD action, and I'm trying to implement it on the client side.

Is there any way to triggered it that way (via Webapi)?
I'm not sure how to implement the Delete record log.
I will be happy to get alternatives also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don’t want to use server side things like Plugin/WF/action and OOB Audit. But everything in JavaScript? You can do it.. its broad.

Start writing js event handlers, customizing with ribbon workbench & button command to include all your custom event handlers to capture before & after values of fields (equivalent of plugin images), insert into custom history entity using webapi, take care of native handlers like save, deactivate, delete,etc.

Apart from plugin which is tailored by product to extend logic of platform execution like this, there’s no alternate from me.